# Array of hashes not being passed by ref to sub

Tags: perl, data-structures, pass-by-reference

I have a setter sub `setAssignmentStatus` which takes an array of hashes (**AoH** from here on) and another parameter (do not concern yourself with this as that part works), and does something iterating through the AoH to set another entry in each hash element.  It does not return anything because I want to use the same AoH object with the added entries after it is pulled through the setter sub and not construct a whole new AoH and repopulate the entries.  Here is the setter:

```
sub setAssignmentStatus
{
    my $fileFlatArySclr = $_[0];
    my $cfgFile = $_[1];

    #here I convert the AoH from the scalar necessary for the sub to its native form
    my @fileFlatAry = @$fileFlatArySclr;

    #this works, don't worry
    my %cfgVarHash = getConfigVars($cfgFile);

    foreach my $fileVarHashSclr(@fileFlatAry)
    {
        #convert each AoH entry from scalar necessary for iteration to native hash
        my %varHash = %$fileVarHashSclr;

        my $varName = $varHash{'VAR_NAME'};

        my $asgnLineCnt = $varHash{'ASGN_CNT'};

        my $asgnSts;
        my $fileAsgnSts; 
        my $cfgAsgnSts; 

        if($asgnLineCnt > 0) { $fileAsgnSts = 1; } else { $fileAsgnSts = 0; }

        my $cfgAsgnLine = $cfgVarHash{$varName};

        if($cfgAsgnLine ne undef) { $cfgAsgnSts = 1; } else { $cfgAsgnSts = 0; }

        $asgnSts = $fileAsgnSts.$cfgAsgnSts;

        #debug to make sure $asgnSts is not null in the first place (it is not!)
        print "\n*** setting ASGN_STUS of ".$varName." to ".$asgnSts;

        #Here we set ASGN_STUS for every iteration
        $varHash{'ASGN_STUS'} = $asgnSts;
    }
}
```

It is called as follows:

> setAssignmentStatus(\@fileFlatAry, $cfgFile);

However, after sending the `@fileFlatAry` AoH through `setAssignmentStatus`, each element hash does not contain an ASGN_STUS entry.  Why is that and how can I fix it?

My suspicion is that I am doing something wrong with the `\` modifier, which is how I am getting the data structure to be passed as a scalar parameter to the sub but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You modify `%varHash` instead of modyfing the referenced hash. Stop copying everything into local variables and modyfying the local variables.

```
$varHash{'ASGN_STUS'} = ...;
```

should be

```
$fileVarHashSclr->{'ASGN_STUS'} = ...;
```

I wouldn't do `my @fileFlatAry = @$fileFlatArySclr;` either. Pure waste.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a copy of an element (or rather, a hash referenced by an element).

Comment: if you wouldn't do `my @fileFlatAry = @$fileFlatArySclr;`, how else would you iterate through the array?

Comment: i had done it like that before.  the reason i do it on a separate line is my preference to make each line of code as simple as possible with as few evaluations on that line as possible.  that ultimately results in more lines of code, however, each line is simple and it is easier for me to maintain that way.

Comment: (And you're really deceiving yourself is you're claiming that `my %varHash = %$otherHash; my $x = $varHash{'ASGN_STUS'};` is easier to read than `my $x = $otherHash->{'ASGN_STUS'};`.)